# Using JDBC: transfer data from tar.gz to MySQL db is becoming slow after ~200k entries

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have been experimenting quite some time during the last days to transform structured (xml) data from a tar.gz (~1.45M distinct files of rather small size) into a more friendly format into a database.

I am not sure what I may disclose of the data or the usecase but I will try my best to explain my efforts.

I have a table with the following columns-types (MySQL; InnoDB):

```
int(11) PK NN UQ
varchar(150) NN
varchar(400) NN
text 
text NN
varchar(45) NN UQ
varchar(80) NN
date NN
text 
varchar(300) 
varchar(300) 
varchar(500) 
varchar(260) 
varchar(200) 
varchar(45)
```

Iterating through the entire tar just looking at the data + parsing takes roughly 90 seconds +/-:

```
try (TarArchiveInputStream tarArchiveInputStream =
                     new TarArchiveInputStream(
                             new BufferedInputStream(
                                     new GzipCompressorInputStream(
                                             new FileInputStream(tarLocation))))){

...
    while ((entry = tarArchiveInputStream.getNextTarEntry()) != null && processedTarEntries < maxNumber) {
    ...PARSING + SOME STATISTICS....
    }
}
```

I hope the following piece of code is sufficient insight into my iteration-process; if not I will try to provide more (totalCount is used in this example to generate the artificial id). The prepared statement is a "normal" INSERT INTO statement.

```
setPreparedStatementValues(preparedStatement, record, totalCount[0]++);

preparedStatement.addBatch();

counter[0]++;

if (counter[0] == BATCH_SIZE){
    counter[0] = 0;
    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    connection.commit();
    watch.stop();
    System.out.println("Elapsed time for batch " + (totalCount[0] / BATCH_SIZE) + ": " + watch.getTime());
    watch.reset();
    watch.start();
}
```

The relevant part of the sout-output is the following (batchsize 5k/10k didn't really make a difference):

```
Elapsed time for batch 29: 3430
Elapsed time for batch 30: 3400
Elapsed time for batch 31: 3553
Elapsed time for batch 32: 3405
Elapsed time for batch 33: 3509
Elapsed time for batch 34: 3544
Elapsed time for batch 35: 6124
Elapsed time for batch 36: 5273
Elapsed time for batch 37: 9171
Elapsed time for batch 38: 8922
Elapsed time for batch 39: 24878
Elapsed time for batch 40: 68124
Elapsed time for batch 41: 70886
Elapsed time for batch 42: 78856
Elapsed time for batch 43: 80879
Elapsed time for batch 44: 85223
Elapsed time for batch 45: 92639
Elapsed time for batch 46: 80106
```

Time seems to be linear until somewhere short before the 40th batch and explodes after that. This output is from an experiment with 300k entries max but where I tried to split it into two seperate runs of 150k entries each. The output is very similar to trying to do all 300k in one go.

I would be very grateful for suggestions what I may be doing wrong if I am or suggestions how to speed this up!